# Read flags specified in a file into a bash array

Tags: bash

Several flags are specified as rows in a text file:

```
--set claimNames.vol1=data1
--set claimNames.vol2=data2
```

I then read this file into an array using:

```
readarray -t array < file.txt
```

Next, "${array[@]}" is added to the following command to include the flags specified in the array:

```
helm install chart_name chart/ --dry-run "${array[@]}"
```

However, the command above adds each flag as a string, meaning the helm command will look like the following and therefore `Error: unknown flag` is raised.

```
helm install chart_name chart/ --dry-run '--set claimNames.vol1=data1'
 '--set claimNames.vol2=data2'
```

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: are you thinking that the single quote around `'--set ...'` are messing things up? Did you try copy/paste same command without the single-quotes? Is the command you have included the output of running with the shell's `-x` option set? Are you sure `--set` is a valid flag for `helm` (of which I know nothing). Good luck!

Comment: Specifically in `bash`, you could run it as `helm install chart_name chart/ --dry-run $(<file.txt)`. That skips the `readarray` as well as KamilCuk's `xargs`, and doesn't require you edit the file. I wouldn't use it for `helm` (or much else) if there's questionable content in that file, but if you know your data is safe it can be a handy CLI hack. (I would be wary using it in any automation.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest is to use xargs

```
xargs helm install chart_name chart/ --dry-run < file.txt
```

Comment: That will probably be OK but YMMV depending on how many flags are present - you could end up with `helm` being called multiple times with subsets of the flags.

Answer (score 1):

For a quick and dirty solution, edit your input file.

As you have it:

```
$: cat file.txt
--set claimNames.vol1=data1
--set claimNames.vol2=data2

$: readarray -t array < file.txt
$: declare -p array
declare -a array=([0]="--set claimNames.vol1=data1" [1]="--set claimNames.vol2=data2")
```

If you put the separate CLI elements on separate lines in the file:

```
$: sed -i 's/ /\n/' file.txt
$: cat file.txt;
--set
claimNames.vol1=data1
--set
claimNames.vol2=data2

$: readarray -t array < file.txt
$: declare -p array
declare -a array=([0]="--set" [1]="claimNames.vol1=data1" [2]="--set" [3]="claimNames.vol2=data2")
```

This should work as you need.

Comment: Or use `readarray -t array < <(tr -s ' ' $'\n' < file)` or similar so you don't have to edit the input file, assuming there's no blanks in the input you do not want converted to newlines.

Comment: Or maybe just `array=( $(<file.txt) )`. Let `bash` do all the work, :)

Comment: That'd be fine as long as `file.txt` didn't contain globbing chars.

Comment: Yeah, I tested redirections and embedded variables and process substitution syntax &c, and those seem generally safe, but a globs are definitely processed. An asterisk could really make a mess of the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

> However, the command above adds each [two-argument] flag as a [single argument ...]
>
> Is there a way to avoid this?

As I emphasized in my quotation above, what you are calling a "flag" is a two-argument pair consisting of an option name and an option argument.  One easy way to make them separate arguments would be simply to put them on separate lines of your file:

```
--set
claimNames.vol1=data1
--set
claimNames.vol2=data2
```

If you don't like that, then you *might* be able to structure them as single arguments by putting an `=` between the option names and their option arguments:

```
--set=claimNames.vol1=data1
--set=claimNames.vol2=data2
```

It is (GNU) standard for GNU-style long options to be expressible that way, but I don't know whether Helm actually supports it.  If Helm uses GNU `getopt_long()` to parse its options (and it probably does) then it will indeed support that; otherwise, maybe.

You should not attempt to perform word splitting on the lines read from the file.  It's possible that you could get a scheme like that to work for your current needs, but it is brittle, and it throws away a lot of the advantage that you are presently gaining from `readarray`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
read -r -d '' -a array < file.txt
helm install chart_name chart/ --dry-run "${array[@]}"
```

- The `-d ''` option with `read` causes the whole input to be treated as one big line.  Newline characters are treated as just whitespace field separators.